# WCF file transfer with cancellation support

Tags: wcf, file-upload

There are a lot of questions regarding file transfer with WCF.
I've got everything working, including larges files in "chunked" mode. 
I have the option to cancel the file upload from the sending party (the one that starts the upload) and  a callback interface to notify when the transfer is accepted, and canceled.

My problem is cancelling the the upload from the receiving end. I can just force the channel to close, but i would like to notify the sending party of the cancellation. 
I'm not getting a solution for this. Any help?

Thanks

Update:

I already figured it out. See the comment below.
The service interface looks like this:

By the way, the  service interface looks like this:

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required, 
CallbackContract = typeof(IFileTransferServiceCallback))]
public interface IFileTransferService
{
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void RequestSendFile(FileTransferInvitation request);

        [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
        void SendData(string id, byte[] data, int length);

        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void SendCancel(string id); 

        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void SendEnd(string id);

        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void RequestSendCancelConfirmed(string id);
}


public interface IFileTransferServiceCallback
{
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void SendStarted(FileTransferInvitation transfer);

        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void RequestSendCancel(string id);

        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void SendCompleted(string id, Exception error);
}
```

Comment: So, once an upload is begun, you already have a working implementation that will tell the service to cancel the upload?  Or you're looking to add that implementation?

Comment: Yes, i already add the option to cancel but only on the client side. What i didn't have was an option to cancel from the server side. 
But never mind i already figured it out:

I added a method on the callback interface to request a cancellation form the server. On the client side i stop sending data, confirm the cancellation to the server and close the channel. 
Its working nicely.

Comment: Make that comment into an answer so people who come looking later will see how you solved the problem.  :)

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution that is working fine:

Added a method on the callback interface to request a cancellation form the server. 
On the client side i use a flag that is set to true when te cancelation request is made. Then stop sending data, confirm the cancellation to the server and close the channel (cleaning up the temp files...).